# Why does my render change when I add background light?

Tags: rendering, light

I was following an Andrew Price tutorial on how to create realistic wood textures in cycles engine. The texture looks good without background light but with it, it looks really white. 
This is probably a really stupid question. Is this meant to happen? Should I only light up my scene using lamps rather than background light?

[image: image without background light]

[image: image with background light]

Comment: It is meant to happen like this. I wouldn't suggest using a white-coloured World for lighting the scene. You can use an HDRi instead for realistic lighting.